# What kind of jQuery function is this?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and still trying to understand the nuances, I think this function calls itself? The function starts off like this:

```
$("#feedpage").live("pageshow", function(e) {
```

Comment: _"I think this function calls itself?"_ - Why do you think that? Are you confused about the `function(e) {` part? The `.live()` function takes two parameters, the first being a string and the second being a function. There are many, many jQuery functions that take a function as a parameter. The concept of passing a function as a parameter is not unique to jQuery, it is a fundamental part of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is a deprecated function in jQuery that binds an event handler to the `document` object for the selected elements (In your case, `#feedpage`). The event handler is triggered when the event named `pageshow` is triggered. As far as I know, there is no `pageshow` event, so it must be a custom event, fired using jQuery functions like [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

The handler is valid for current and future elements on the page, thanks to event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

The `live` method attaches an event handler to all selected elements.
In your example the `function(e) {..}` is the event handler that will be attached to the `pageShow` event of all elements that match #feedpage.

Check http://api.jquery.com/live/